# Click event not handled on li click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to launch a click event on an `li` but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#menu ul li").click(function(){
      alert(this.id);
   });
});
```

```css
    .wrapper {
     display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 2fr 7fr 2fr;
        grid-template-areas: 
          "left header  header"
          "left    content ad"
          "left    content ad"
          "footer footer  footer"
       }
    
    .header{
     grid-area:header;
     position: sticky;
     top:0;
     background-color: red;
     height: 100px;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .left-sidebar{
     grid-area:left;
     top:0;
     background-color: #22262A;
        position: sticky;
        height: 100vh;
        padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
        font-size: 26px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    
    .left-sidebar a{
     padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
     color:#000;
     display: block;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .nav a:hover{
     background-color: #272b30;
    }
    
    .ad{
     grid-area:ad;
     background-color: navy;
    }
    .content{
     grid-area:content;
     padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
     background-color: yellow;
     height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .footer{
     grid-area:footer;
     background-color: grey;
     height: 125px;
    }
    
    #logo{
     margin-top: 50px;
     margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    
    .no-list{
     display: block;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #menu ul li{
     background-color: yellow;
     z-index: 500;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="header">
 </div>
 <div class="ad">advertisements</div>
 <div class="left-sidebar">
  <nav id="menu">
   <a href="#" data-target="home" class="" id="logo">Sylent</a>
   <ul class="nav" id="test2">
    <li id="getBierTest" onclick="alert()">try</li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
 <div class="content">main content div</div>
 <div class="footer">footer div</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I used this in another project and it worked. But this time I'm using CSS grid and suddenly it doesn't. Any ideas what might caused this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error do you get? The snippet is working, so looks like something wrong with your setup. Make sure that you load js after the page is loaded.

Comment: it seems snippet is working.

Comment: [I can't see your code to fail](https://jsfiddle.net/0a3hzy62/) ..?

Comment: your snippet is working

Comment: I do not get an error but it is alerting the id now. Think it might be the css that i'm using

Comment: maybe in your code you have your JS where you attach the event handler before your html?

Comment: I added the JS after document is ready @Kristianmitk

Comment: Works perfectly for me

Comment: Apperently the problem isn't the script, it is the CSS. The nav seems to overlap the li that's probably why i'm not getting anything.

Comment: Then Add CSS as well in code snippet

Comment: Getting everything what might cause it

Comment: Added the CSS. I don't know how to add it to the snippet though

Comment: I've added the CSS to the snippet and it still works.  There's something else affecting this.

Comment: yea trying to get a work around now :)

Comment: @Archer I've added "data-target" to each <li> and then i can get the onclick

Comment: Sorry but that's irrelevant, in the code above.  You're not telling us something fundamental so we cannot help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've copied your code into a Codepen:
https://codepen.io/chrisboon27/pen/NYYNvJ?editors=1111 
The only problem I can see is that two alerts fire. The first one is empty, but the second one works. This happens because as well as adding the event via jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#menu ul li").click(function(){
      alert(this.id);
   });
});
```

you are also calling alert inline in your html, but without any arguments, so you just get an empty alert:

```
<li id="getBierTest" onclick="alert()">try</li>
```

If you remove the inline alert it might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is absolutely correct. But always make sure that you a load JS after the page is fully loaded. Use [`$(document).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function to do that.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#menu ul li").click(function(){
      alert(this.id);
   });
});
```

Comment: Got that! forget to add is in the question.

Answer (score -2):

try this if you are trying to target specific li

```
$("#menu ul li").on('click', function(){
   alert(this.id);
});
```

More optimized solution can be

```
$(document).on('click', '#menu ul li',function(){
   alert(this.id);
});
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: How does this differ in functionality than it's snippet? His code actually works, you're just posting an optimisation for it.

Comment: optimized for what?

Comment: I eat the apple...
The apple is eaten by me :D

Comment: That's a less optimized "solution" that will handle *every single element* being clicked, but ignore the ones that don't match the selector.  This is a bad suggestion and not relevant.

Comment: Please also explain how to handle those who does not match with selector?